# Consider the ring $R=\mathbb{Q}[x]$

Tags: ring-theory

$\newcommand{\QQ}{\mathbb{Q}}$
Consider the ring $R=\QQ[x]$ over $I$ where $I$ is an ideal of $\QQ$ generated by the polynomial $x^2-2$ in $\QQ[x]$.

(a) Show that for all $f(x)$ in $\QQ[x]$, $f(x)+I=(a+bx)+I$ is in $\QQ[x]/I$.

(b) Find the linear representative  of the polynomial $f(x)=x^4+2x^2+x+2$ in $R$.

(c) Show that $x^2-2$ is irreducible over $\QQ[x]$.

For part (c) I know the polynomial is irreducible; I beg for the rest. Thanks.

Comment: Hint for (a): use the fact that $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is a Euclidean domain, and perform division with remainder on $f(x)$ by $x^{2}-2$. For (b), note that in $\mathbb{Q}[x]/I$, $x^{2} \equiv -2$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\QQ}{\mathbb{Q}}$
Part a): Since $\QQ$ is a field, you know $\QQ[x]$ is a Euclidean domain w.r.t. degree. So, given $f(x) \in \QQ[x]$, you can use the division algorithm:
$$ \exists q, r \in \QQ[x] \quad f(x) = (x^2 - 2)q(x) + r(x) \quad \textrm{where } r(x) = 0 \textrm{ or } \deg r < \deg f $$
What can do you do from here?

Part b) should follow from a) pretty straightforwardly.

Part c): Use the Rational Root theorem, if you have it available, and the fact that a polynomial of degree two or three is reducible iff it has a root.

Comment: Great answer, giving plenty to work with but not too much. +1

Comment: @Henry:should I take now I+f(x)? I see I cant get the results

Comment: You want to show that $f(x) + I$ and $(a + bx) + I$, which are both elements of $\mathbb{Q}[x]/I$, are equal. (Well, you want to show there exist $a,b$ for which that is the case.) What is a criterion for telling if two cosets of an ideal are equal?

Comment: @Henry:  I got x+10 as a representative polynomial, have I done the right thing?

Comment: Yep, that's correct!

Comment: @Henry:from your point of view in (a),I am thinking of letting r(x)=a+b(x)=0,then since f(x)+I is in R⁄I follows the same as f(x)+I={f(x)+q(x)(x^2-2)}={ax+b}.what about this, am I far from your view?

Comment: Pretty much. What I was thinking was: we want to show there exists $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $f(x) - (ax + b) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]/I$. Apply the division algorithm to get $f(x) = q(x)(x^2 - 2) + r(x)$. Rearranging gives $f(x) - r(x) = q(x)(x^2 - 2) \in I$. We just need to show $r(x)$ is of the form $ax + b$. How can we do this?